# Meaning of a "!" in this context

Tags: functions, notation

In my "Foundations to Pure Mathematics" module, one of the slides, talking about Bijective functions defines it as follows:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a function. Then $f$ is bijective if $f$ is both injective and surjective. This means that, for each $y \in Y$, there is exactly one point $x \in X$ with $f(x) = y$. A bijection is a bijective function.

He then follows this definition by writing: $\forall y \in Y \exists ! x \in X:  f(x) = y$

Does the "!" in this context have any significant meaning, or is it just emphasizing the $\exists$?

Comment: It means "there exists a $\underline{\text{unique}}$ $x$..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means there exists a unique $x$.  It is shorthand for $$\exists x\left(( \operatorname{stuff}(x)) \wedge (\forall y (\operatorname{stuff}(y)) \implies x=y)\right)$$